# Import MooseX::Method::Signatures into caller's scope

Tags: perl, import, moose, syntactic-sugar

I've made a "bundle" module which does a bunch of things: imports `Moose`, imports `true`, `namespace::autoclean`, makes the caller's class immutable (taken from `MooseX::AutoImmute`). The one thing I haven't been able to figure out is how to include `MooseX::Method::Signatures`.

Here's what I've got so far:

```
package My::OO;

use Moose::Exporter;
use Hook::AfterRuntime;

use Moose ();
use true ();
use namespace::autoclean ();

my ($import, $unimport, $init_meta) = Moose::Exporter->build_import_methods(
 also => ['Moose'],
);
sub import {
 true->import();

 my $caller = scalar caller;
 after_runtime { $caller->meta->make_immutable };

 namespace::autoclean->import(-cleanee => $caller);

 goto &$import;
}
sub unimport {
 goto &$unimport;
}

1;
```

The idea is that in my code, I can now do things like this:

```
package My::Class; {
    use My::OO;
    extends 'My::Parent';
    method foo() { ... }
}
```

but right now I still have to include an extra `use MooseX::Method::Signatures;`. How can I include that into my OO module?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First off, please note that the implementation of `Hook::AfterRuntime` is quite fragile. While it works for many simple things, it's extremely easy to end up with very hard to debug errors. I'd recommend just writing the `->meta->make_immutable` yourself, or using other approaches to get around writing it, like `MooseX::Declare`, for example.

To answer your actual question:

```
MooseX::Method::Signatures->setup_for($your_caller);
```

Comment: +1 for MooseX::Declare! Seriously Moose is cool, but if one is to make Perl OO easy, take it all the way. For example I am working up a Perl-based *onopoly clone called [`Opoly`](https://github.com/jberger/Opoly) and part of my reason for trying was to do a full project in MooseX::Declare, and its great